# ExtJS 4.2 dataview - how to know if item is selected

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

HI I have a DataView with XTemplate.

In my controller, I listen to the `itemclick` event.

```
onItemClick: function(view, record, item) {
        var me = this,
            panel = me.getRightPanel();

        // here I need to know if the item clicked is already selected

}
```

> Is there a way to know if the item clicked is already selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call [`getSelectionModel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-method-getSelectionModel) on your `DataView` object and then call [`getSelection`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-getSelection) on the result.  This would give you an array of `Model` objects.  After that, just check if object `record` (the parameter to `onItemClick`) is in the array.